# One Dimensional Heterostructures

Tags: material-science, nanoscience, exotic-matter

Van Der Walls Heterostructures stack different single layer materials together.
However, just as a layer of various graphene sheets form graphite with weak bonding in between making the layers easily slide out of order, how do can you prevent Van Der Walls heterostructures from sliding past each other and breaking the structures, considering they have lower attraction between them than even graphene layers in graphite?